# Border Hide in Scroll Horizontal

Tags: html, css

I want to show border bottom in item have active class. But border can't show because parent element #outer use `overflow:hidden` this usage for scroll horizontal.

this is my HTML code

```css
#outer {
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
#inner:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}

#number .active {
    color: #000000 !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FF0000
}

#number a {
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    color: #c4c4c4;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="number" class="col col-md-10">
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="inner"><a href="#" class="active">
        1
      </a><a href="#">
        2
      </a><a href="#">
        3
      </a>
      </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Any ideas for this problem ?

Comment: add to #outer => padding-top: 5px;    padding-bottom: 5px;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a `padding-bottom` like below.
It really depends on your use case though.

```css
#outer {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

#inner:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#number .active {
  color: #000000 !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FF0000
}

#number a {
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: #c4c4c4;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="number" class="col col-md-10">
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="inner"><a href="#" class="active">
        1
      </a><a href="#">
        2
      </a><a href="#">
        3
      </a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could also use `inline-grid` to make sure the items are properly cleared.

```css
#outer {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-grid;
}

#inner:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#number .active {
  color: #000000 !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FF0000
}

#number a {
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: #c4c4c4;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="number" class="col col-md-10">
  <div id="inner"><a href="#" class="active">
      1
    </a><a href="#">
      2
    </a><a href="#">
      3
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```